# Custom Post Type Registration Function Hides Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a function to register custom post types but for some reason after I add this code the Pages, other Posts and Custom Field Groups, disappear from the admin of WordPress. Here is my Register Function.

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function property() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Properties', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Property', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Property Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Property Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Properties', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Property', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'property_type' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'property', 0 );
```

I know its an issue with this function, because when I remove it the pages reappear.

Comment: Have you turned on errors? Place the following code at the top of the file, or preferably in your php.ini if you have access to it:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);` ... This will display any errors and their descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't call a custom post "post_type" this is your issue, try to change the name of custom post.

```
register_post_type( 'something_else', $args );
```

Comment: That was it thank you. I thought that I had to call it something else but when I did before it removed post type from the taxonomy. This time it worked though so I must have done something wrong before.

Comment: Glad to help :)